# defaults equivalent to read value from plist in MacOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: macos, zsh, default, macos-catalina

Has any one tried to read plist file value in shell script after updating to latest MacOS 10.15.x(Catalina)? Initially I used to read it with "defaults read .." but now the same file is throwing some error like "The domain/default pair of () does not exist". Did anyone have any clues on this? I think my terminal is using zsh instead of sh.

Sample of existing to store value in variable 
`NAME=$(defaults read sample.plist name)`

Comment: now i tried ```NAME=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print ":name"' sample.plist)``` and it is working as expected. But not sure is this the correct way to use it!!

Now, I need to read an array value using the same with comma separated values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would use plutil instead, you can extract a key with it then output say an array as a json object and parse that instead

Comment: `defaults` always adds “.plist” to the domain name to get the filename, so you need to leave it off. Your command is looking for a file named “ sample.plist.plist”.

Comment: i tried leaving ".plist" in the filename, same issue exists